LyX preview environment doesn't work since I've updated lyx
Ever since I updated LyX to 2.4 from 2.3.7 I've had these problems:

whenever I open an older file (which was created before LyX 2.4) I get the following pop-up, and I don't know how to stop it from happening, those files have no changes at all.


the preview environment doesn't work at all (the file compiles and everything it's just inside the LyX document the preview environment does nothing).



Just a guess (I  still have the 2.3.7):   I think that the pop-up allow simply allow you to think twice before to convert a older lyx format to the new format.  I have no idea of what it could change really, if some,  but  suppose that change some like the encoding and you have something in the old document not supported with the new encoding. This could be a nightmare if you are not enough experience with LaTeX to know how restore the original enconding. In this case, It doesn't hurt to let you know...

@Fran i defenitly dont have experience debugging these sort of problems. but the pop-up shows up everywhere now, I've created some new files for testing and it didn't do it for the first few minutes but after a while even on those new files created completely on LyX2.4, these show up.

Regarding Question 2: LyX's LaTeX requirements have changed with version 2.4. Make sure that you have and cprotect.sty and suffix.sty installed. (The latter is part of the  bigfoot package.)

yeah, that was it for me, I talked it over in the mailing list, and I'll try to ask there about my first problem here as well.
